# Do not trigger Javascript scroll event when user clicks an anchor link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, anchor, addeventlistener

The below code detects when the user is scrolling and if there scrolling up it shows the head nav. Nice and tidy, problem I am having however is I have some anchor links on the page, if I click an anchor link that jumps the user up the page this also triggers, which causes some annoying behaviour. I am trying to find a nice simple solution that would not trigger this when the user clicks or does a keypress. This sits inside a vuejs nuxt mixin.

```
this._onUserScroll = () => {
      if (window.pageYOffset < 0) {
        return;
      }
      if (Math.abs(window.pageYOffset - this.lastScrollPosition) < OFFSET) {
        return;
      }
      this.navBar =
        window.pageYOffset < this.lastScrollPosition ;
      this.lastScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
    };
this._onUserScroll();
window.addEventListener("scroll", this._onUserScroll);
```

Comment: please share your `a` tags and where are you putting that code

Comment: you would probably need to do something like this with a global var: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734067/is-it-possible-to-disable-a-scroll-function-when-a-user-clicks-an-anchor-link-t